# Implementação de algoritmo em VisuAlg

Tags: algoritmo, if, visualg

Faça  um  programa  que  receba  dois  números  e  execute  uma  das  operações  listadas  a  seguir de  acordo com  a  escolha  do  usuário. Se  for  digitada  uma  opção  inválida   mostrar mensagem de erro e terminar a execução do programa. As opções são:  1. Média entre os dois números. 2. Diferença do maior pelo menor. 3. O produto entre os dois números.

```
Nome:Exercicio6
Objetivo:mostrar a mensagem de erro
Dados de entrada:
Saida: dois numeros
Variaveis:                                         TA CERTO DESSE JEITO QUE MAIS
                                                           EU FAÇO SEI LA
    inteiro num1
    inteiro num2
    inteiro opcão
Inicio 
    Leia num1
    Leia num2
    Leia opcão
```

Comment: Você já conhece o `if-else` (ou `se-então`)? E o `leia`? Então, leia a escolha do número e ponha numa variável. Se essa escolha for 1, faça uma coisa, se for 2 faça outra e se for 3, faça a terceira coisa.

Comment: O objetivo não é mostrar uma mensagem de erro, pois não há nada que possa ser chamado de erro aqui. Você já começou bem, agora o próximo passo é colocar o conjunto de `se-então-senão` corretos verificando as opções. Depois, para cada `então` você faz o cálculo correspondente e mostra o resultado na tela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei muito bem programar no `VisualG` não, mas acredito que seja essa a lógica:

```
Variaveis:
    inteiro num1
    inteiro num2
    inteiro opcão
Inicio 
    Leia num1
    Leia num2
    Leia opcão
    Escolha opção
        Caso 1
        Escreva (num1 + num2) / 2
        Caso 2
        Se num1 > num2 Faça
            Escreva num1 - num2
        Senão
            Escreva num2 - num1
        Caso 3
            Escreva num1 * num2
        Outro Caso
            Escreva "Opção invalida"
Fim
```

O `Escolha` verifica sua variável e executa um código de acordo com isso. Acredito que era isso que você estava procurando.

Answer (score 0):

```
variaveis
inteiro num1
inteiro num2
inteiro opcão
Inicio 
Leia num1
Leia num2
Leia opcão
Escreva (Escolha opção:
         1 - Média entre os dois números. 
         2 - Diferença do maior pelo menor. 
         3 - O produto entre os dois números.
  leia opção
    se opção = 1
    Escreva (num1 + num2) / 2
    se opção = 2
    Se num1 > num2 Então
        Escreva (num1 - num2)
    Senão
        Escreva (num2 - num1)
    se opção = 3
        Escreva (num1 * num2)
    Outro Caso
        Escreva "Opção invalida"
 Fim

           FIZ DESSE JEITO DEI UMA MODIFICADA TBM DA CERTO SE FIZER ASSIM
```